# Habilitar botão ao clicar em um checkbox

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou tentando fazer que com que ao apertar no checkbox escrito "Sim", habilite o botão de enviar. Porém, só consigo fazer isso se apertar no botão de "Não" também.

Segue o código HTML:

```
    <label>Sim</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sim" name="sim" ng-model="sim" required>

    <label>Não</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nao" name="nao" ng-model="nao" required>
```

Segue o script:

```
<script>
  
    let mudar = document, [inputs, validar] = [
        mudar.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]'),
        mudar.querySelector('#btnsend')] 

        validar.disabled = true
    
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('input',() => {
        let values = []
        inputs.forEach(v => values.push(v.value))
        validar.disabled = values.include('')
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz de uma maneira mais extensa e que com certeza pode ser melhorada, mas pro momento, está funcional!

SCRIPT & HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.is(":checked")) {
      var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";

      $(group).prop("checked", false);
      $box.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $box.prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sim').click(function() {
    if ($('#sim').is(':checked')) {
      $('#btn').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#btn').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
  $('#nao').click(function() {
    if ($('#nao').is(':checked')) {
      $('#btn').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#btn').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <!-- checkbox do "sim" -->
  <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fooby[1][]" id="sim" />Sim</label>

  <!-- checkbox do "não" -->
  <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fooby[1][]" id="nao" />Não</label>

  <!-- botão -->
  <input type="submit" name="btn" id="btn" disabled value="botão"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!

Answer (score -3):

Posso te dar uma alternativa, mais simples e funcional.

Ao invés de usar `checkbox`, utilize os campos do tipo "`radio`" com o mesmo `name`. Pois ele aceirará apenas uma das duas opções, já o checkbox aceitaria selecionar as duas ao mesmo tempo. Assim utilizando "radio" e selecionando o `NÃO` automaticamente desmarca o `SIM`.

Então, criamos um evento `change` que seja chamado no momento em que selecionamos o check **"Sim"**. E criamos um mesmo evento para o check **"Não"**, que no caso de selecionado, automaticamente desabilite o botão.

Segue o código (adicionei o botão "Enviar" para testar):

```
<label>Sim</label>
<input type="radio" id="sim" name="liberaBotao" ng-model="sim" required>

<label>Não</label>
<input type="radio" id="nao" name="liberaBotao" ng-model="nao" required> 

<button type="submit" id="botao-enviar" disabled> Enviar </button>
```

Script:

```
const checkSim = document.querySelector("#sim");
const checkNao = document.querySelector("#nao");
var botaoEnviar = document.getElementById("botao-enviar");

checkSim.addEventListener("change", (el) => {   
    if (checkSim.checked) {
            botaoEnviar.disabled = false;
    } 
});
checkNao.addEventListener("change", (el) => {   
    if (checkNao.checked) {
            botaoEnviar.disabled = true;
    }
});
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Muito obrigada!